# NASM MOV from register to buffer

Tags: assembly, syntax, nasm

I'm really lost here, because I'm getting invalid combination of opcode and operand errors no matter how I try this piece of code. I've declared a buffer in .bss, but I can't move a value to that location from a register, and I can't figure out why.

```
    numArgs:     resb 4
    mov dword    numArgs, [esp+4]
```

Obviously I'm just trying to retrieve the number of command line arguments given. If there's an easier way to do this, I'm all ears, but I'm particularly concerned with why I can't mov a value into a memory buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't move memory to memory like that. You'll have to do

```
mov eax,[esp+4]
mov [numArgs],eax
```

Or:

```
push dword [esp+4]
pop dword [numArgs]
```